# The necessary and sufficient condition for a unit element in Euclidean Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to prove that in Euclidean domain D with Euclidean function ***d***, *u* in D is a unit if and only if ***d***(*u*)=***d***(1).

Suppose ***u*** is a unit, then there exist ***v*** in D such that ***uv***=1, this implies ***u***\1 so ***d***(*u*)<=***d***(1), but obviously 1 divides ***u*** so ***d***(1)<=***d***(*u*). Hence, ***d***(u)=***d***(1).

Conversely, suppose  ***d***(u)=***d***(1), since *u* is not zero, there exist *q* and *r* in D such that  1=uq+r with r=0 or ***d***(r)< ***d***(u).

If r=0 then u is a unit. Else ***d***(r)< ***d***(u) =***d***(1), this implies ***d***(r)< ***d***(1). I stop here, because I failed to argue that r must be zero.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Does your $d$ satisfy $d(xy)\le d(x) d(y)$? In other words, what is your definition of Euclidean domain? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition for a discussion.

Comment: My Euclidean domain is arbitrary, so there is no need to define the function d. I cannot say d satisfies d(xy)<=d(x)d(y).

Comment: How do you conclude that $d(u)\le d(1)$ from $u\mid 1$? I suggest you spell out your definition of Euclidean domain in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $d(x) \le d(xy)$.

Comment: Saying d(x)<=d(xy) is the same as saying d(x)<=d(y) whenever x divides y. What you suggest about spelling the definition is good, but if D is a Euclidean domain, then the definition follows trivially.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the text of your question I assume that your $d$ function satisfies $d(x)\le d(z)$ if $x$ divides $z$. (BTW, this is the same as saying that $d(x)\le d(xy)$.)

Since $1$ divides every element, we have $d(1)\le d(x)$ for all $x$. If $u$ is a unit, then $u$ divides $1$ and so $d(u)\le d(1)$. This implies $d(u)=d(1)$.

Conversely, as you have remarked, $1=uq+r$ with $r=0$ or $d(r)< d(u)$. But if $d(u)=d(1)$, then if $r\ne0$ you'd get $d(r)<d(1)$, which contradicts $d(1)\le d(x)$ for all $x$. Hence $r=0$ and $u$ is a unit.

Comment: Yes, d(1)<=d(x) for all x is what I forget. Thanks for your help lhf.

Comment: I think $d(1)\leq d(x)\forall x\ne0$ is true but we have to assume the norm is positive ($d(x)>0\forall x\ne0$)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is different from the case that $d(a)\leq d(ab)$. The Euclidean function just satisfies the [fundamental division-with-remainder property (EF1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69537/1102065) and we define that $d(ab)=d(a)d(b)$. Thus we cannot apply the fact that $d(1)\leq d(x)$ since $1$ divides every element. Here is my proof.

Suppose $a\in R$ is a unit, and let $ab=1$. Then $d(ab)=d(a)d(b)=d(1)$. Since $d(1)=d(1)d(1)$, we have $d(1)=0$ or $1$. If $d(1)=0$, then $d(a)=d(1)d(a)=0$. If $d(1)=1$, then $d(ab)=d(a)d(b)=d(1)=1$. Obviously $d(b)\geq 1$, so $d(a)\leq d(1)$. And $d(a)\geq 1=d(1)$, hence $d(a)=d(1)$.

Conversely, suppose $d(a)=d(1)$, then there exist $q$ and $r$ such that $1=qa+r$. If $r\neq 0$, then $d(r)<d(a)=d(1)=0$ or $1$. Moreover, $d(r)=0$ and $d(1)=1$ since $0\leq d(r)<d(1)$. Let $r=xy$, where $x,y\neq 0$, and d(r)=d(x)d(y)=0. Without loss of generality, let $d(x)=0$, and there exists $u,v$ such that $y=ux+v$. Obviously $d(v)\geq d(x)=0$, we have $v=0$, and then $d(y)=d(u)d(x)=0$. Therefore, $d(r_0)=0$ for all $r_0$ that devides $r$. Thus $d(1)=0$ for $1\mid r$, a contradiction. Hence $r=0$, $1=qa$, i.e., $a$ is a unit of $R$.